# Splitting sentence for use with message

Tags: message

Have got a long message that I want to split up into two parts and pass them to the `message` command.

```
(message "This sentence to split")
```

How can I split the sentence in a way that is acceptable to `message` because the following in incorrect.

```
(message "This sentence " "is split")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newlines when using message](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72254/newlines-when-using-message)

Comment: No because in this particular situation I would like to keep the indentation.

Comment: 1. No, you haven't posed a different question. The question says *nothing about indentation*. And the code you give doesn't show anything having anything to do with indentation. 2. The *same answer* was provided, by @dalanicolai.

Comment: I recommend you try harder to clearly specify what you're looking for. Please study [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you get better help.

Comment: ok good.  Did not specify as I did not know that continuing on next line starts at the left most side.

Comment: If you agree that the question is a duplicate, please just delete it. No need to wait for more close votes. Better to avoid more answers spread among duplicate questions, whether or not any of those duplicates eventually get closed. Thx.

Comment: Use `concat`? `(message (concat "This sentence " "is split"))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either enter a backslash and press `RET`:

```lisp
(message "Some string \
rest of string")
```

or you can use `concat`

```lisp
(message (concat "Some string "
                 "rest of line"))
```

Comment: `concat` does the job.