# Newlines when using message

Tags: message, newlines

Is this the way to add newlines to message string?

```
(message "Some string \n Another string")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, or add the newline by pressing `RET` (enter)

```lisp
(message "Some string
Another string")
```

Comment: I did not know this one.